# How can I calculate shipping charge based on order current time in Shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I want to calculate the shipping charge based on order time.

Suppose, customer can place the order between 12:00 am - 11:58 am then the charge will be 20$. and if he can place the order 11:59am - 11:59pm then the charge will be 15$.

How can I do this thing in Shopify? Is there any app available for it?

Comment: Not in easy way, unless you have shopify plus. I can elaborate if you want to know more

Comment: Yes, I want to more, can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Your real problem here is not really one of Shopify, so much as definitions. As you well know, the time in one place on the planet is not always the same at another. So my 10:45 am might just be 14:45 pm at the server. So if the server is to correctly decide which shipping price to show me, does it consider the 14:45 pm where it is, or the 10:45 am where I am? Or to even make things more interesting, perhaps it only matters where the shipping company is. So let us assume the customer is at 10:45 am, the server is at 14:45 pm, and the shipping company is at 12:45 pm. What do we say? Easy? I think once you clarify how that scenario plays out, only then can you code for it.

Now that you decided to let the server time rule, add a custom carrier services script via an API call to your store. Shopify sends each checkout payload to an endpoint you specify, where you look at the time, decide the shipping amount the customer pays, and return the payload (simple JSON) to Shopify. The store then collects the shipping rate you decide.

Comment: Let's take a server time. Ignore customer time ,because we are using that store for only one specific country